# ORACLE SQL - how do I make a count, but the select has more attributes than I want to group?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, count

I have following relations:

*emp*: `(eid:integer, ename:string, age:integer, salary:decimal(10,2))`

*works*:`(eid:integer, did:integer, pct_time:integer)`

*dept*: `(did:integer, dname:string, budget:decimal(10,2), managerid:integer)`

**Expected outcome:**

Create a view ManagerSummary that lists for every department the department name, manager ID and manager name, manager salary and the number of employees in that department. The view will have five columns with headings: *DeptName*, *MgrID*, *MgrName*, *MgrSalary* and *EmpCount*

**What I've tried:**

```
Create View ManagerSummary(DeptName, MgrID, MgrName, MgrSalary, EmpCount) 
AS Select D.dname, D.managerid, E.ename, E.salary, count(E.ename) 
FROM Dept D, Emp E, Works W 
Where D.did = w.did AND E.eid = w.eid 
GROUP BY D.dname;
```

I want to make the count on the employees, but I cannot group only on the department. When I group over the department, the managerid, the employee name and the salary, the counts will all be 1. That doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the aggregation with a derived table and then join to that. That way you don't need to to group by all columns in the main query (and very often it's faster as well).

By using an outer join you also include departments without employees (don't know if that can happen):

```
create view manager_summary
as
select d.dname as department_name, 
       e.eid as mgr_id,
       e.ename as mgr_name, 
       e.salary as mgr_salary,
       coalesce(w.num_employees,0) as emp_count
from dept d
  join emp e on e.eid = d.managerid
  left join (       
    select did, count(distinct eid) as num_employees
    from works
    group by did
  ) w on w.did = d.did
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the manager information, you want to join `dept(managerid)` on `emp(eid)`. Then you can bring in table `works` and aggregate.

Consider:

```
create view ManagerSummary(DeptName, MgrID, MgrName, MgrSalary, EmpCount) 
as select 
    d.dname, 
    d.managerid, 
    e.ename, 
    e.salary, 
    count(*) 
FROM dept d
inner join emp e on e.eid = d.managerid
inner join works w on d.did = w.did 
group by 
    d.dname, 
    d.managerid, 
    e.ename, 
    e.salary
```